# Как перемещать элементы State в Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

Учусь Редаксу. Делаю учебный проект Бесконечные подсписки. Идея такая: при запуске есть поле + кнопка "Добавить". В поле вводится текст, нажимается "Добавить", выше поля появляется этот текст и 2 кнопки "Удалить", "Добавить подсписок". И так далее. По сути набирается список. При нажатии "Добавить подсписок" создается подсписок, в него добавляется поле + конка "Добавить" и так до бесконечности.

Использую Редакс. Стейт организовал в виде массива объектов. Требуется сделать возможность передвигать (по нажатию кнопок "Вверх" , "Вниз" на элементах списка) элементы этого стейта. Вроде б сделал перемещение, вижу, что это происходит установив расширение Редакса в хроме, но вот на экране оно не рендерит изменения. Что я не так делаю ?
Код прилагаю.

````
``` {length >= 2 && index != 0 && index != 1 && index != length - 1
                    ?
                    <React.Fragment><MyButton>Up</MyButton><MyButton>Down</MyButton></React.Fragment>
                    : length > 2 && index == 1 ? <MyButton onClick={() => dispatch(
                        moveUp(element))}>Up</MyButton> : length > 2 && index == length - 1 ?
                        <MyButton onClick={() => dispatch(moveDown(element))}>Down</MyButton> : null
                }```

```const moveUp = (arr, val) => {
        let index = arr.indexOf(val);
        if (index !== arr.length - 1) {
            arr[index + 1] = arr.splice(index, 1, arr[index + 1])[0];
        } else {
            arr[0] = arr.splice(index, 1, arr[0])[0];
        }
        return arr;
    }```

```case actions.MOVE_UP:
            return moveUp(state, action.payload)``` \\action.payload - это элемент стейта-массива
````

Answer (score 0):

Если стэйт меняется, ищи проблему в перерисовке компонента. Посмотри, перерисовывается ли компонент после твоих изменений

Comment: Ага, вроде б вышло. Решил так: return arr.map(item => item);